# Failed to convert parameter value from string to datetime

Tags: c#, formatting

```
myCommand1.Parameters.Add("@I_vBACHNUMB", SqlDbType.Char).Value = GLHdr.BACHNUMB;
myCommand1.Parameters.Add("@I_vREFRENCE", SqlDbType.Char).Value = "ExcelImport";
myCommand1.Parameters.Add("@I_vTRXDATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = GLHdr.TRXDATE;
```

In last line I have value  `GLHdr.TRXDATE: "15-02-2017"`.

I am getting format exception.Let me know where I am doing mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GLHdr.TRXDATE` is a *string*, not a `DateTime`.

You need to parse it into a `DateTime` before passing it through:

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse(GLHdr.TRXDATE);
myCommand1.Parameters.Add("@I_vTRXDATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt;
```

Note that `DateTime.Parse` *can* fail, so `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` that also take a format string may be more suitable for you specific circumstances.